# Unexpected behavior of Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation in Mathematica:

```
Solve[
  {A^2 + B^2 - P^2 - Q^2 - 2 A X + 2 P X - 2 B Y + 2 Q Y == 0, 
   C^2 + D^2 - R^2 - S^2 - 2 C X + 2 R X - 2 D Y + 2 S Y == 0}, 
  {X, Y}]
```

Instead of solving the equation in `X` and `Y`, Mathematica reduces it to

> ```
> Solve B^2
> ```

and says Wolfram|Alpha doesn't yet know how to respond to your exact query for the first set of equations.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Solve B^2` is not output from *Mathematica* and your equation works fine for me (*Mathematica* 10.2).  Start with a fresh kernel and I suspect it will work for you.

Comment: @JimB Excuse my lack of knowledge because I am a total beginner. I don't understand what you mean by "start a fresh kernal" so I just closed Mathematica and restarted it and clicked on "new Notebook". After that I clicked the (+) sign which showed many options including "Free Form Input". Once, I clicked on it and copied the above equation, I still got the same result.

Comment: @iKnowNothing When you click on that plus sign, select "Wolfram Language Input", not Free form. Or simply start typing your code in. Free form input is expected to be expressed in natural language and is further interpreted. You should not use it if you already have code. See this guide: [Free-Form & External Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html).

Comment: Don't use: `D`,because is a bulid-in function(derivative).

Comment: Thank you everyone. It is working as expected now. :)

Comment: A rule of thumb in coding (especially in Mathematica) is to use a descriptive lowerCamelCase for your own definitions because many built-ins are in UpperCamelCase.